# use of 'fopen' on non OS Arm board

Tags: c++, embedded, arm

I am working on a Non- OS supported Arm Board.I have tested my c++ code on my desktop computer.Its working fine.Now I have to dump the bin file generated after cross compiling the code using arm-elf-g++. 
My code is opening a file to read its content using fopen command but will this thing work for the board as no OS is there, so no file system?

Thanks
vid09

Comment: If there is no operating system then there's likely no filesystem. Are you linking with a library that can handle file operations?

Comment: You have answered to your question... if there is no file system, what is a file?

Comment: Your libc may fake files, we can't tell. Provide the relevant details please.

Comment: thank you everyone for clearing my confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you opening the file to read it - what is that data?

You could provide it to your embedded code in other ways.  For example

- compile it in as a constant
- read it in over some port (a serial port maybe, or Ethernet - although the latter is a big job with no O/S!) and use the host to send the data over.

Comment: The actual the code which is working on my Desktop, takes the filename as a argument and opens it and this happens in different c files .I thought if fopen worked I need not modify at all the places.

Answer (score 3):

Your target library will most probably have an fopen() stub; a non-functioning empty function definition that you need to replace with a working version.  This is known as *retargetting*.  Without retargetting, your code may well compile and link, but the fopen() call and any other standard I/O calls including printf() for example will do nothing.

How you retarget depends on your compiler's standard C library.  In Keil/RealView you can modify one of the supplied retarget.c examples and link it with your project.  If you are using Newlib (commonly used with bare metal GNU toolchains), you need to modify or reimplement the *syscalls* stubs.  Other toolchains will have similar methods.

However that is all rather academic since to open a file you have to have a file system, which in turn requires that you have some form of media with data on it that can be read as a file.  All that can be done on a bare-metal system, but it involves both additional hardware and software.  See [FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) for example.  Adding an SD or MMC card via an SPI interface for example is relatively simple in hardware terms.  You could of course implement a RAM disk or a file system on on-chip Flash, but you still have to consider how to get data onto such a file system in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

A common way of using file I/O on baremetal is for debugging. In this case it's usually implemented using [semihosting](http://doc.ironwoodlabs.com/arm-arm-none-eabi/html/getting-started/chap-cs3.html).

> CS3 is designed to support boards without an operating system. To
>   allow functions like `open` and `write` to work without operating system
>   support, a *semihosting* feature is supported, in conjunction with the
>   debugger.
>
> With semihosting enabled, these system calls are translated into
>   equivalent function calls on your host system. You can only use these
>   function calls while connected to the debugger; if you try to use them
>   when disconnected from the debugger, you will get a hardware
>   exception.

Obviously, this won't work in stand-alone setting.

However, you can opt to implement the necessary calls yourself. This depends on what C runtime library you're using; here's a tutorial on how to do it for Newlib: http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/industry-comment/4023922/Embedding-GNU-Newlib-Part-2